# How to enable onseek thumbnail view for Youtube

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

In this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylLzyHk54Z0 when I hold the player knob in the progress bar and drag it forward, it shows a chain of thumbnails. But when I go to this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36AP68tGoAs, same dragging does not generate the thumbnail trail.
I tried to embed videos with some options (using YouTube API), but could not find the solution.

Can someone please help?

I just want to enable to thumbnail trail when dragging the progress bar for YouTube, Specifically when embedded using YouTube JavaScript API.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: One of my friends from US suggested that he can get the trail view in <http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36AP68tGoAs> too. I am from India. Is it something location specific?